# Need to duplicate the same element in the DOM 4 times using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Im using jquery to insert html in the dom. Everything is working fine, now i need to duplicate an element 4 times, and i don't know how.

this is how i use Jquery to insert the element into the DOM.

```
function Pin(caixaPin){
 var $temp;
  $temp = $("<div></div>");
  $temp.addClass("caixaPin");
  $temp.html(caixaPin);
  $("body").append($temp);
}

Pin('<div></div>');
```

Thanks !!

Comment: using `.clone()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eL3usbxb/

```
function Pin(caixaPin){
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
        var $temp;
        $temp = $("<div></div>");
        $temp.addClass("caixaPin");
        $temp.html(caixaPin);
        $("body").append($temp);
    }
}

Pin('<div></div>');
```

**Another way**
Just call Pin function inside a loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Pin('<div></div>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help !! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Pin('<div></div>');
}
```

There you go. Basic for loop from 0 to 3 (4 times). And calling `Pin` inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the Help !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just execute your function pin in loop

Comment: Thanks for the Help !! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to create X amount of Y, like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
{
    $('body').append('<div class="caixaPin"></div>')
}
```

what this does is define j as 0, when it gets to 3 and including 3, append `<div></div>` to the body. Hope this helps

Comment: Should also add the class into the append method. I.e., $('body').append('<div class="caixaPin"></div>');

Comment: @Joel I'm just doing an example code :) but I'll update the code just to avoid confusion :)